# Docker compose commands are not working from user data?

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, docker-compose, terraform-provider-aws, user-data

I'm trying to install drupal on AWS ec2 instance by using terraform. I have created a script file in that I have defined docker installation and the s3 location of docker-compose.yml  after that I run the docker-compose up -d command in the script. I called the script file in the user data everything is working fine on the new AWS ec2 instance except docker containers are not starting up.docker-compose file has downloaded to the instance but they were no containers actively running. If again I login into the instance and run the command then both drupal MySQL containers are starting and the drupal website is in an active state but the same command from the script is not working.

```
#! /bin/bash
sudo yum update -y
sudo yum install -y docker
sudo usermod -a -G docker ec2-user
sudo curl -L https://github.com/docker/compose/releases/download/1.21.0/docker-compose-`uname -s`-`uname -m` | sudo tee /usr/local/bin/docker-compose > /dev/null
sudo chmod +x /usr/local/bin/docker-compose
sudo service docker start
sudo chkconfig docker on
aws s3 cp s3://xxxxxx/docker-compose.yml /home/ec2-user/
docker-compose up -d
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Solved it with:
    ln -s /usr/local/bin/docker-compose /usr/bin/docker-compose